# Java 6 EE Navigate to Error Page When Getting JSonParseException

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, exception

I am working with PrimeFaces 5.0, Java 6 ee.

**How can i navigate to error.jsf page when com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException occurs?**

It doesn't matter which java class throws the JsonParseException . I have to handle the Exception in wherever it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a error xhtml page.
In your web.xml you can configure error-page elements that act upon some error-code or exception-type. Typically, you might configure at the end of your web.xml the following:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsfpages/errorpages/errorPage500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <error-code>503</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsfpages/errorpages/errorPage503.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsfpages/errorpages/errorPage500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

to handle ajaxrelated exception you can use omnifACES FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory.

http://balusc.blogspot.in/2012/03/full-ajax-exception-handler.html